# Extend data frame with missing dates by group and interpolate

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["A", "A", "A" ,"B", "B"], "date":["06/24/2014","06/26/2014","06/29/2014","07/02/1999","07/04/1999"], "value": ["4","6","9","2","4"] })


ID        date value
0  A  06/24/2014     4
1  A  06/26/2014     6
2  A  06/29/2014     9
3  B  07/02/1999     2
4  B  07/04/1999     4
```

For each group, I want to extend the data frame to include all the missing dates between the max and the min of the dates, and then interpolate the column value linearly. The result should look like this:

```
 ID        date value
0  A  06/24/2014     4
1  A  06/25/2014     5
2  A  06/26/2014     6
3  A  06/27/2014     7
4  A  06/28/2014     8
5  A  06/29/2014     9
6  B  07/02/1999     2
7  B  07/03/1999     3
8  B  07/04/1999     4
```

My idea so far is as follows:

Set date as the index:

```
df.date = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date)
```

Group by ID and apply the following function:

```
B = df1.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(x.date.min(),x.date.max()), fill_value=0) )
```

What would be the best approach for this?

thank you,

Comment: can you post the desired df?

Comment: Yes, I'll simplify it a little bit so that its easy to see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to do some initial conditioning to ensure proper dtypes

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["A", "A", "A" ,"B", "B"],
                   "date":["06/24/2014","06/26/2014","06/29/2014","07/02/1999","07/04/1999"],
                   "value": ["4","6","9","2","4"] })


df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.value = pd.to_numeric(df.value, 'coerce')

df = df.set_index('date')
```

#### Solution

```
df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False).value \
    .apply(lambda df: df.resample('D').interpolate()).reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you piRSquared, that looks great. A few questions: 1) why didn't you have to specify a date_range like pd.date_range(df.date.min(), df.date.max()) ? does resample already take care of that? 2) what does group_keys=False do? and 3) why is it necessary to do this step? df.value = pd.to_numeric(df.value, 'coerce')

Comment: Also, for some reason, when i run it, it skips the interpolation and prints out NaNs instead

Comment: @dleal good followups 1) yes, `resample` takes care of the range. 2) when I use `apply` on a `groupby` instead of one of the "off the shelve" methods, it will drop the things I grouped by into result.  I already took care of that, so I said `False`.  3) your dataframe had strings for values.  When I did this at first, it failed because it can't interpolate strings.  So I turned them into numeric things that can be interpolated.  `'coerce'` handles the off chance that a string cannot be forced to numeric and will return `np.nan` instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right, 3) is why it was skipping the interpolation. Thank you so much for the clarifications piRSquared

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
In [6]: df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').resample('D').pad())
Out[6]:
              ID value
ID date
A  2014-06-24  A     4
   2014-06-25  A     4
   2014-06-26  A     6
   2014-06-27  A     6
   2014-06-28  A     6
   2014-06-29  A     9
B  1999-07-02  B     2
   1999-07-03  B     2
   1999-07-04  B     4
```

Comment: that looks good MaxU, however, I would like to interpolate 'value' according to the dates, so the first would be 4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: @dleal, i think piRSquared's solution is w you were looking for

Comment: yes thank you, instead of using pad, i would use interpolate. I appreciate your answer however

Comment: @dleal, if you want to use interpolate you have first to convert `value` column to numeric dtype (`int` or `float`), otherwise it will not work